# how to sort data stored in file in c

Tags: c, sorting

With the help of these code i am able to get the data but not able to sort it.my question is how to sort the data in file i am not getting the logic for it. i can retrieve data but not able to sort it.

For Ex. file data:

```
john,
ash,
billy,
doe
```

Expected Output:

```
ash,
billy,
doe,
john
```

my work:

```
int main ( void )
{
    FILE *file = fopen ( "college.text", "r" );
    int i, j;

    char arra[128][128],temp[128];

    char line[128]; /* or other suitable maximum line size */

    for(i=0; i<128; i++)
        for(j=0; j<128; j++)
            arra[i][j] = '\0';

    for(i=0; i<128; i++)
        line[i] = '\0';

    if ( file != NULL )
    {
        i=0;

        while ( fgets ( line, sizeof line, file ) != NULL ) /* read a line */
        {
            strcpy(arra[i], line);
            printf("%s ", arra[i]);
            i++;
        }

      //   for(i=0; i<128; i++)
      //   {
      //      for(j=0; j<128; j++)
      //      {
      //         if(strcmp(arra[i],arra[j])>=0)
      //         {
      //            temp=arra[j];
      //            arra[j]=arra[i];
      //            arra[i]=temp;
      //  }
      //  }
      // }
      // printf("%s ", arra[j]);

      fclose ( file );
    }
    else
    {
        perror ( "college.text" ); /* why didn't the file open? */
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: just ask google: https://www.google.com.au/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=array%20sort%20in%20c

Comment: [example](http://c.happycodings.com/sorting-searching/code6.html)

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4433186/sorting-a-text-file

Answer (score 0):

Change your second loop from
for(j=0; j<128; j++) to
for(j=i+0; j<128; j++) and try.

Comment: could you please copy the modified portion.